# Three JS gives Cross Origin error with S3 Bucket (used as CDN)

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, three.js, cross-domain

```
function renderItem() {
    initializeScene();
    THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setTexturePath('https://cdn.rubyrealms.com/textures/');
    mtlLoader.setPath('https://cdn.rubyrealms.com/objects/');
    mtlLoader.load('DefaultSkin.mtl', function(materials) {
        materials.preload();
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,1.4);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath('https://cdn.rubyrealms.com/objects/');
        objLoader.load('DefaultSkin.obj', function(object) {
            scene.add(object);
            fitCameraToObject(camera, object, 5.5, controls);
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        });
});

showScene();
```

I keep getting an error in the console THREE.WebGLState: DOMException: "The operation is insecure."

I've added the development site to the CORS configuration using "https://rubyrealms.com" but I continue to get this error between the site and my S3 bucket (CDN). I have tried everything I can think of and that I've read but nothing seems to work.
    }

Answer (score -3):

Edit: Alright, try this:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");
mtlLoader.setTexturePath('https://cdn.rubyrealms.com/textures/');
```